# Spring Kafka Template implementaion example for seek offset, acknowledgement

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am new to `spring-kafka-template`. I tried some basic stuff in it and they are working fine. But I am trying to implement some concepts mentioned at [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/index.html) like :

1. [Offset Seeking](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#seek)
2. Acknowledging listeners

I tried to find some example for it over net but was unsuccessful. The thing only I found is its source code.

We have a same issue as mentioned in this post [Spring kafka consumer, seek offset at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996882/spring-kafka-consumer-seek-offset-at-runtime).

But there is no example available to implement the same.

Can someone give any example on how to implement them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ConsumerSeekAware` for that purpose to deal with seeks:

```
static class Listener implements ConsumerSeekAware {

     private final ThreadLocal<ConsumerSeekCallback> seekCallBack = new ThreadLocal<>();

     public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        this.seekCallBack.set(callback);
    }

@KafkaListener(...)
        public void listen(@Payload String foo,
                Acknowledgment ack) {

                this.seekCallBack.get().seek(topic, partition, 0);
            }
        }

}
```